# Spring Instantiation using a none-static factory method

Tags: spring, configuration

I have got a situation where I would like to create bean2 in Spring config:

beans.xml:

```
<bean id="bean1" class="...">
    <property name="..." ref="..." />
</bean>
```

bean2 = bean1.foo()

Would appreciate any help,

Thanks,
Behzad

Comment: Do you need an annotation config or via XML? I'll post how to do that with annotations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use instance factory method. See [corresponding chapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-class-instance-factory-method) in Spring documentation.

```
<bean id="bean2" factory-bean="bean1" factory-method="foo"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using annotations you can use:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public Bean1 getBean1(){
        return Bean1.getInstance();
    }

    @Bean
    public Bean2 getBean2() {
        return this.getBean1().newBean2(); //in your example is this.getBean1().foo();
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, thank u, but I am using xml-configuration Eugene's answer was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: That's ok, I only mantain this answer only for those who needs accomplish that using annotations. Thanks for your answer.